# Pst-geo3d sans / without contours

Tags: xetex, pstricks, mapping, pst-geo

Je me demande s'il est possible de dessiner une carte sans contour avec `pst-geo3d` (compilation: xelatex). J'ai besoin de zones de couleur pour la terre et pour l'eau et de la possibilité de placer les villes par la longitude et la latitude, donc `pst-geo3d`. Maintenant, j'essaie de me débarrasser des contours noirs. Infructueux:

I am wondering whether I stand any chance drawing a borderless/contourless map with `pst-geo3d` (compilation: xelatex). I need color areas for land and ocean and, above all, the possibility to place locations via longitude and latitude, hence `pst-geo3d`. But my attempts to get rid of the black border contours have been fruitless so far:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{pst-map3d}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture*}(-0.49\linewidth,-0.5\textheight)(0.49\linewidth,0.5\textheight)
\psset{PHI=13.88,THETA=121.77,unit=10,path=/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-geo/data}
\WorldMapThreeD[gridmap=false,circles=false,mapcolor=gray!30,oceancolor=white,borders=false,borderwidth=0]
\pnodeMapIIID(121.066667,14.65){Quezon City}
\psdot[linecolor=red,dotsize=0.02](Quezon City)
\uput[u](Quezon City){\psframebox*[opacity=0]{\small{Quezon City}}}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

Merci pour votre idée. / Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  Questions on this site are usually just written in English, cf. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676, but it is nice with some variety.

Comment: :) But since the package documentation is only available in French ... Just wanted to make sure that I would reach the right audience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `islandcolor=gray!30` for `\WorldMapThreeD`:

[image]